# Modify DataSet to accept Comparable objects

Tags: java, comparable

I need to modify DataSet to accept Comparable Objects. The tester will not compile and I do not know how to print out the compareTo method. Should I be using an ArrayList for the tester? Thanks ahead of time!

```
public interface Comparable
{
/**
 Compares this object with another.
  @param other the object to be compared
  @return a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer if this object
  is less than, equal to, or greater than, other
*/
int compareTo(Object other);
}
```

---

```
public class DataSetComparable
{
private double sum;
private Object maximum;
private Object minimum;
private int count;
private Comparable comparer;

/**
  Constructs an empty data set with a given measurer.
  @param aMeasurer the measurer that is used to measure data values
*/
public DataSetComparable(Comparable acomparer)
{
  sum = 0;
  count = 0;
  maximum = null;
  minimum = null;
  comparer= acomparer;
}

/**
  Adds a data value to the data set.
  @param x a data value
*/
public void add(Object x)
{ 
sum = sum + comparer.compareTo(x);
  if (count == 0 || comparer.compareTo(maximum) < comparer.compareTo(x))

     maximum = x;

    if (count == 0 || comparer.compareTo(minimum) > comparer.compareTo(x))

    minimum=x;
    count++;

}


/**
  Gets the largest of the added data.
  @return the maximum or 0 if no data has been added
*/
public Object getMaximum()
{
  return maximum;
}

/**Gets the smallest of the added data.
*@return the minimum or 0 if no data has been added
**/

 public Object getMinimum()
{
  return minimum;
}
}
```

---

```
 public class String implements Comparable {

private String input;
private int holder;

public String(String aninput){
    input= aninput;
    holder=0;
}

public String getComparer(){
    return input;
}

public String getString(){
    return input;
}

public int compareTo(Object other){
    String temp= (String) other;
    if(input.compareTo(temp)<0){
        holder=-1;  
    }
    else if (input.compareTo(temp)== 0) {
        holder= 0;
    }
    else{
        holder= 1;
    }
    return holder;
}
 }
```

---

```
 public class StringTester{
public static void main (String [] args){

  Comparable c = new String();
  DataSetComparable data = new DataSetComparable(c);

  data.add(new String("Jimmy"));
  data.add(new String("Amy"));
  data.add(new String("Melissa"));
  data.add(new String("Melissa"));

  String max = (String) data.getMaximum();
  String min = (String) data.getMinimum();

  System.out.println("Maximum String = " + max);
  System.out.println("Minimum String = " + min);
}
 }
```

More specifically, the error says:

> constructor String in class String cannot be applied to given types.

Comment: More specifically, the error says: constructor String in class String cannot be applied to given types.

Answer (score 2):

Your code includes this:

```
 public class String implements Comparable {
      ...
 }
```

Do you realize that there is a standard Java library class called `String` that gets imported by default into every class?  If implement your own class called `String` you are going to get some very confusing compilation error messages.

I strongly recommend that you change the name of your class to something else; e.g. `StringHolder`.

---

Note, technically you *could* define a class called `String`.  However the rules that Java uses to disambiguate the names of classes are not designed for this use-case ... and you will end up having to refer to `java.lang.String` by its fully qualified name wherever you use it.  And other people reading / modifying your code would find that really awkward / annoying.

It is best to treat the names of classes in the `java.lang` package as "reserved", and don't define classes with the same (unqualified) name.

Comment: I changed the class name to StringHolder and the same problems still persisted. It is this line of code that the program finds an error:
Comparable c = new String();

Comment: Well `java.lang.String` implements `java.lang.Comparable` not your `Comparable` interface.  Another example of your previous mistake.  But in this case, the fix is to get rid of *your* version of the `Comparable` interface and just use the standard one.